# Отфильтровать список словарей по другому списку словарей

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть 2 списка словарей

```
lst1 = [{'name': 'city', 'status': True}, {'name': 'id', 'status': True},
             {'name': 'flag', 'status': True},{'name': 'country', 'status': True}]
lst2 = [{'name': 'class_id', 'datatype': 'varchar(10)', 'encoding': None, 'class': None},
                 {'name': 'city', 'datatype': 'varchar(100)', 'encoding': None, 'class': None},
                 {'name': 'country', 'datatype': 'varchar(100)', 'encoding': None, 'class': None}]
```

Нужно отфильтровать первый список и получить значения, которых нет во втором.
Должно получиться так:

```
lst = ['id', 'flag']
```

Пробовал так:

```
 [d["name"] for d in lst1 for t in lst2 if d["name"] != t["name"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку задачка по сути про множества, это проще всего сделать через разность множеств `set1.difference(set2)`

```
print(list(set(x['name'] for x in lst1).difference(x['name'] for x in lst2)))
```

```
['flag', 'id']
```

Answer (score 0):

в лоб можно сделать так:

```
arr1 = []
for obj in lst1:
    arr1.extend(obj.items())

arr2 = []
for obj in lst2:
    arr2.extend(obj.items())

res = {elem[1] for elem in arr1 if elem not in arr2}
```

Тут я искал вообще по всем ключам (не только по `name`)

Ну или если для `name`:

```
arr1 = []
for obj in lst1:
    for key, value in obj.items():
        if key == 'name':
            arr1.append((key, value))

arr2 = []
for obj in lst2:
    for key, value in obj.items():
        if key == 'name':
            arr2.append((key, value))

res = {elem[1] for elem in arr1 if elem not in arr2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
set_list2 = set(map(lambda x: x['name'], lst2))

print([ele for ele in lst1
       if ele['name'] not in
       set_list2])
```

При желании можно отказаться от переменно set_list, и засунуть её в генератор, но тогда map будет вычисляться каждую итерацию, что не очень хорошо.